# Display JSON Data in HTML Table

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I get the following JSON String from server as response

```
[{"city":"AMBALA","cStatus":"Y"},{"city":"ASANKHURD","cStatus":"Y"},{"city":"ASSANDH","cStatus":"Y"}]
```

Here is my Jquery Code

```
$('#search').click(function() {
    alert("submit handler has fired");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'cityResults.htm',
        data: $('#cityDetails').serialize(),
        success: function(data){ 
            alert(data);    
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
    return false;//suppress natural form submission
});
```

The alert shows the JSON String Correctly. Now i want to map this response to my table

say

How can i do that  ??

Comment: Not using php using Spring MVC

Comment: how will someone know ? add related tags to your question

Comment: @Abhishek Singh, what is cityDetails, I have same problem could you help me on this,                                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28479576/how-to-populate-table-with-json-object-which-is-return-by-server

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this:

CSS:

```
.hidden{display:none;}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="table" class="hidden">
    <tr>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('#search').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'cityResults.htm',
        data: $('#cityDetails').serialize(),
        dataType:"json", //to parse string into JSON object,
        success: function(data){ 
            if(data){
                var len = data.length;
                var txt = "";
                if(len > 0){
                    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                        if(data[i].city && data[i].cStatus){
                            txt += "<tr><td>"+data[i].city+"</td><td>"+data[i].cStatus+"</td></tr>";
                        }
                    }
                    if(txt != ""){
                        $("#table").append(txt).removeClass("hidden");
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
    return false;//suppress natural form submission
});
```

Comment: there is a slight error in code logic `if(data[i].city && data[i].city)` should read `if(data[i].city && data[i].cStatus)`

Comment: this is correct but this append in previous data table if we call again and again how can i remove previous data and append new coming data to the `#table`. Help please.

Comment: @BikashSaud you can clear table before appending.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to the answers you already have, and for others that come accross this post. I recently had a similar task and created a small jquery plug in to do it for me. Its pretty small under 3KB minified, and has sorting, paging and the ability to show and hide columns.

It should be pretty easy to customize using css. More information can be found here http://mrjsontable.azurewebsites.net/ and the project is available for you to do as you wish with on github https://github.com/MatchingRadar/Mr.JsonTable

To get it to work download the files and pop them in your site. Follow the instructions and you should end up with something like the following:

```
<div id="citytable"></div>
```

Then in the ajax success method you will want something like this

```
success: function(data){ 
    $("#citytable").mrjsontable({
        tableClass: "my-table",
        pageSize: 10, //you can change the page size here
        columns: [
            new $.fn.mrjsontablecolumn({
                heading: "City",
                data: "city"
            }),
            new $.fn.mrjsontablecolumn({
                heading: "City Status",
                data: "cStatus"
            })
        ],
        data: data
    });
}
```

Hope it helps somebody else!

Answer (score 3):

There are many plugins for doing that. I normally use datatables it works great. http://datatables.net/

Comment: Not the most direct answer, but +1 for data tables. Great little tool

Answer (score 2):

```
          <table id="myData">

          </table>

           <script type="text/javascript">
              $('#search').click(function() {
                    alert("submit handler has fired");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'cityResults.htm',
                        data: $('#cityDetails').serialize(),

                        success: function(data){ 
                            $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
                               var row = $("<tr><td>" + value.city + "</td><td>" + value.cStatus + "</td></tr>");
                               $("#myData").append(row);
                            });
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                            alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;//suppress natural form submission
                }); 

   </script>
```

loop through the data and append it to a table like the code above.

Answer (score 1):

I created the following function to generate an html table from an arbitrary JSON object:

```
function toTable(json, colKeyClassMap, rowKeyClassMap){
    let tab;
    if(typeof colKeyClassMap === 'undefined'){
        colKeyClassMap = {};
    }
    if(typeof rowKeyClassMap === 'undefined'){
        rowKeyClassMap = {};
    }

    const newTable = '<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped" />';
    if($.isArray(json)){
        if(json.length === 0){
            return '[]'
        } else {
            const first = json[0];
            if($.isPlainObject(first)){
                tab = $(newTable);
                const row = $('<tr />');
                tab.append(row);
                $.each( first, function( key, value ) {
                    row.append($('<th />').addClass(colKeyClassMap[key]).text(key))
                });

                $.each( json, function( key, value ) {
                    const row = $('<tr />');
                    $.each( value, function( key, value ) {
                        row.append($('<td />').addClass(colKeyClassMap[key]).html(toTable(value, colKeyClassMap, rowKeyClassMap)))
                    });
                    tab.append(row);
                });

                return tab;
            } else if ($.isArray(first)) {
                tab = $(newTable);

                $.each( json, function( key, value ) {
                    const tr = $('<tr />');
                    const td = $('<td />');
                    tr.append(td);
                    $.each( value, function( key, value ) {
                        td.append(toTable(value, colKeyClassMap, rowKeyClassMap));
                    });
                    tab.append(tr);
                });

                return tab;
            } else {
                return json.join(", ");
            }
        }

    } else if($.isPlainObject(json)){
        tab = $(newTable);
        $.each( json, function( key, value ) {
            tab.append(
                $('<tr />')
                    .append($('<th style="width: 20%;"/>').addClass(rowKeyClassMap[key]).text(key))
                    .append($('<td />').addClass(rowKeyClassMap[key]).html(toTable(value, colKeyClassMap, rowKeyClassMap))));
        });
        return tab;
    } else if (typeof json === 'string') {
        if(json.slice(0, 4) === 'http'){
            return '<a target="_blank" href="'+json+'">'+json+'</a>';
        }
        return json;
    } else {
        return ''+json;
    }
};
```

So you can simply call:

```
$('#mydiv').html(toTable([{"city":"AMBALA","cStatus":"Y"},{"city":"ASANKHURD","cStatus":"Y"},{"city":"ASSANDH","cStatus":"Y"}]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use datatable if you want to get result from json object. Datatable also works in the same manner of converting the json result into table format with the facility of searchable and sortable columns automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Convert JSON Data to HTML Table</title>
        <style>
            th, td, p, input {
                font:14px Verdana;
            }
            tr{
                align: right
            }
            table, th, td 
            {
                border: solid 1px #DDD;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                padding: 2px 3px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            th {
                font-weight:bold;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="CreateTableFromJSON()" value="Create Table From JSON" />
        <div id="showData"></div>
    </body>

    <script>
        function CreateTableFromJSON() {
            var obj = {[{"city":"AMBALA","cStatus":"Y"}, 
                      {"city":"ASANKHURD","cStatus":"Y"}, 
                      {"city":"ASSANDH","cStatus":"Y"}]}

    var table = document.createElement('table');

    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);

    function iterate(obj,table,tr){

        for(var props in obj){

            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(props)){

                if(typeof obj[props]=='object')
                    {
                        var trNext = table.insertRow(-1);
                        var tabCellHead = trNext.insertCell(-1);
                        var tabCell = trNext.insertCell(-1);
                        var table_in = document.createElement('table'); 
                        var tr_in;
                        var th = document.createElement("th");      
                        th.innerHTML = props;

                        tabCellHead.appendChild(th);
                        tabCell.appendChild(table_in)
                        iterate(obj[props],table_in,tr_in);
                    }
                else
                    {
                        if(tr === undefined)
                        {
                            tr = table.insertRow(-1);
                        }
                        var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                        console.log(props+' * '+obj[props]);
                        tabCell.innerHTML = obj[props];
                    }

            }
        }
    }

    iterate(obj,table,tr);

    var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
            divContainer.innerHTML = "";
            divContainer.appendChild(table);

    }
    </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML:
 <div id="container"></div>   
JS:


$('#search').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'cityResults.htm',
        data: $('#cityDetails').serialize(),
        dataType:"json", //to parse string into JSON object,
        success: function(data){ 

                var len = data.length;
                var txt = "";
                if(len > 0){
                    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){

                            txt = "<tr><td>"+data[i].city+"</td><td>"+data[i].cStatus+"</td></tr>";
                            $("#container").append(txt);
                    }



        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

check below link to convert JSON data to standard HTML table in the simplest and fastest way.

http://crunchify.com/crunchifyjsontohtml-js-json-to-html-table-converter-script/